# Replace string in php

Tags: php

I have this string:

525,294,475,215,365,745

and i need to remove 475..and comma.
and if i need to remove first number i need to remove also the next comma, also for last.
I can i do?
a regular expression?
thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a regular expression:

```
$s = "525,294,475,215,365,745";
$s = preg_replace(',?475', '', $s);
```

Comment: can i replace 475 with a variable?

Comment: @Ste - You can, but the regular expression Donald suggested wouldn't work if you are trying to remove the first element in the list because there wouldn't be a ",". The safer way would be to explode the string into an array, remove the element, and then combine the array back to a string.

Comment: @Ste - You could, like this: $num = 475; $s = preg_replace(",?$num", '', $s); Notice the double quotes.

@XSaint32 - The ? after the comma makes it optional, so it should match both (475) and (,475).

Comment: @XSaint32 - Ah, you are correct - removing the first element would leave a comma behind. Perhaps "(,?$num)|($num,)" would work instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
$newStr = str_replace(',475', '525,294,475,215,365,745');
```

Or the less error prone way:

```
$new = array();
$pieces = explode(',', '525,294,475,215,365,745');
foreach ($pieces as $piece) {
   if ($piece != 475) {
      $new[] = $piece;
   }
}

$newStr = implode(',', $new);
```

Comment: explode is soon to be deprecated,  I suggest using preg_split("/,/") instead

Comment: @mhughes Since when is explode deprecated?

Comment: @Mike C. It's not deprecated yet, it is scheduled ( or at least was, after all the php 6 debacle).  php >= 5.3.0 recommends replacing explode with preg_split

Comment: @Mike C.  sorry, my memory failed me, split was deprecated in >= 5.3.0 : http://www.mantisbt.org/bugs/view.php?id=10973

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = "525,294,475,215,365,745";

$parts = explode(',', $data);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($parts); $i++) {
    if ($parts[$i] == 475) {
        unset($parts[$i]);
    }
}

$newdata = join(',', $parts);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$bigString = "525,294,475,215,365,745";
$pos = strpos($bigString, ",");
while($pos != false) {
  $newString .= substr($bigString, 0, $pos);
  $bigString = substr($bigString, $pos + 1);
  $pos = strpos($bigString, ",");
}
echo $newString;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function filterValue($index, &$a) 
{
    $key = array_search($index, $a);
    if ($key != false) {
        unset($a[$key]);
    }
}


// Original data
$data = "525,294,475,215,365,745";
$data = explode(',', $data);

filterValue('475', $data);
$output = implode(',', $data);
```